# Is it possible to invoke a javaScript server side?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

greetings all
i was wondering if it's possible to send some javaScript code in the response of a controller
meaning that i want to invoke a javaScript but not from the jsp (from server side)
something like:

```
var d = new Date();
var gmtHours = -d.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
var tz=gmtHours;
window.location="page?tz="+tz;
```

what do you think guys ?

Comment: There are several ways. Exact answer depends on the functional requirement. Please elaborate. What is it you're trying to achieve/solve?

Comment: i have a remembered user which may try to access any page in the application, and i want to detect his timezone before accessing the required page, i have an interceptor that intercepts this user before accessing required page.

Comment: Use `@nickname` to automatically notify others about comments. As to the requirement: can't you just pass it along during submitting the login form? What do you need the client side timezone for after all? Have you considered to just make it an user-controlled preference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to the answer:

Executing JavaScript when the answer comes back from the server. To do that you can wrtite a Javascript in html, something like

```
<script>
    alert("This code just executed");
</script>
```

usually people have something like

```
<script>
    function init() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].focus();"
    }
    window.onload = init;
</script>
```

It will execute your function when windows loads.

It looks like you want to know the timezone for the user you are displaying results to. As mentioned, HTTP headers don't have this information, so you need to submit it or store as user preference. 
If you don't want to store it, you either need to add it to every submit or URL. This way you will always have timezone on server side and you don't need to do 2 round trips.

The workflow might look like this: 
1. User submits form or clicks a link -> 2. you form the results on server side -> 3. display results on client side.

Looks like you want to show some dates/times specific to timezone. If you send data to the client using ajax, you can then get it in javascript before step 3 and change it according to your preferences. 
If you want to do all the formatting on server side you need to submit the timezone with the original request in step 1. 
You can add 2 more steps 1.2 submit timezone request as a response to user action. 1.3 Re-submit the request with timezone info using javascript. This is not optimal, but could work.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not very clear about the question. But it you are asking to invoke a javavscript when a response comes back from server than you can use AJAX and do your processing in the callback.

If you want to access the timezone than another way to send it as part of the parameter right in the beginning as a request parameter itself.

Comment: i want to get user time zone before loading a specific page (meaning in the get request of the page)

Comment: We had a similar problem in one of the project. The Http payload (including headers) do not contain time zone information by default. So we sent the time zone parameter as part of the request when we needed it. If you have clear entry points in the application, send the parameter as part of request from those pages.